# NSURLSessionDataTask does not work from unity plugin

Tags: ios, plugins, unity-game-engine, nsurlsession

I have a native iOS sdk that works great in a native ios app, but when I try wrapping it in a unity plugin and call it from unity on an iOS device (ios v6.1), a specific piece of code of an HTTP request is fired but seems to never return:

```
NSURL* url = // I init some URL here
NSURLSessionConfiguration* cfg = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:cfg
                                                      delegate:nil
                                                 delegateQueue:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
req.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// send the request
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
    [session dataTaskWithRequest:req
               completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                   // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED FROM WITHIN A UNITY APP
               }
     ];

[dataTask resume];
```

Any ideas why?
p.s. I am using NSURLSession because I need to configure things like special headers, etc, and it seems to be the recommended approach for modern iOS versions..

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

found the problem: the test device was iOS 6.x, whereas NSURLSesssionXXX classes are iOS7+, but the strange thing is that the unity xcode project did not say anything about it, nor were there any exceptions at runtime.. I switched to using NSURLConnection with operation queues to become compatible with iOS 6.x...